# Preventing items from showing in trade depot menu

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I want to filter all the Artifacts I've made so I won't trade them by accident. Also, not being able to do so prevents me from marking entire Item types when I have 1 Artifact of that type somewhere between many items.
Is there a way to make an item not show in the trade menu (but not be forbidden)?

Answer (score 2):

While I'm not sure how to accomplish quality filtering in Trade, I would start with making a stockpile that accepts any goods, armor, furniture and so on and set the quality filter to "artefact". I'm pretty sure that d-b-f (or whatever mass forbidding is) everything in the stockpile should prevent that stuff from showing up on the trade haul menu.